# C++ mongocxx driver stored javascript issue

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have created some stored procedures(stored javascript) in my mongodb database. Now i need to call this from a c++ program. I just installed mongocxx  driver. is there any api available for calling stored javascvript from c++??

Comment: I have just searched for any api available for that. Doesn't find one.

Comment: What is a stored javascript? Just plain text in a file?

Comment: Stored JS in MongoDB is saved in the system.js collection.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876049/mongodb-stored-procedure-equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only features of MongoDB that use server-side stored javascript are described in the manual page [Server-side Javascript](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/).

There is no C++ driver API to call such functions.