# Possible ways to run direct Mongo queries in C# like SQL queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am unsing Mongo DB and C# (.Net) to build my web application. I want to run Mongo queries in my .Net application like SQL queries using ADO.net. What are the possible ways to run direct Mongo queries in C# ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Stored Procedure Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876049/mongodb-stored-procedure-equivalent)

Answer (score 2):

I think your definition of a MongoDB query is something like this:

```
{"Name": "Name 1"}
```

That is a valid json, if yes try below code in C#:

```
// `queryString` is a MongoDB query in json format
var queryString = @"{""Name"": ""Name 1""}";

// `query` is a `BsonDocument` generated by `queryString`
var query = BsonDocument.Parse(queryString);
// You can use `TryParse()` also ...

// Now you can use that `query` in `Find()` like this:
var result = await col.Find(query).ToListAsync();
```