# Trigger and Store Procedure in Mongodb , Nodejs and Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

Hello I'm new in Angular and Nodejs. I come from .NET background . Is it possible to make trigger and Store procedure in Mongodb with Node Js Api. If it possible please provide me some idea. I couldn't find any source about it .

Answer (score 0):

Mongo DB does not support stored procedures. Have a look at this: [MongoDB Stored Procedure Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876049/mongodb-stored-procedure-equivalent)

And this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

That being said, according to the docs, seems that storing a script is simply saving the function code into `db.system.js` collection

Hope this helps